# Doctrine NestedSet provokes Lock wait timeout exceeded?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine NestedSet behavior for a while now without any 
problem but I'm just facing a new issue today while using createRoot() 
or other behavior methods after a save(); 
Doing something like :

```
$myObject()->save(); 
$myTree = Doctrine::getTable('myClass')->getTree(); 
$myTree->createRoot($myObject);
```

gives me that exception :

```
Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

I'm not sure it's a Doctrine bug but something coming from my db 
(MySQL) because Doctrine code hasn't change on my server. 
Looks like the save() operation locks the table and the update query 
from the createRoot fails. 
Note that the related table is pretty small (25 lines) and everything 
was working well recently... 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: any changes on your db server?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but I found it.
The bug was caused by a slight modification on my code which was acting differently between dev and prod environment. This piece of code is related to Doctrine_Query which I override to handle master/slave connections. Some kind of dumb effect side, very difficult to debug.

Thank you for help.